# What's your sound fx library expectation and needs?

Tags: sound-design, field-recording, library-sound-effects

I am looking for various thematic for next sound library that I will create.
What are the sounds that you almost never found,that you need, or you don't find with significant quality , feeling, identity, or another parameters... ?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for participating, but questions asking for lists are generally a bad fit for this site since every answer is equally valid and would quickly get off-topic. http://sound.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: See this meta question for advice on making list questions a bit more useful and future-proof (specifically, make it about a specific and harder to answer use-case).

Comment: More info still: http://meta.sound.stackexchange.com/questions/39/shopping-questions/40#40

Answer (score -1):

For me crowd/people effects are the hardest to come by. Usually because the number of people, acoustics and behavior are almost always specific to the scene. And free ones are never long enough.